# Storm nimbus incorrectly bind to localhost

Tags: apache-storm

Below is my config file:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "10.13.0.91"
    - "10.13.0.93"
    - "10.13.0.104"

nimbus.seeds: ["10.13.0.91", "10.13.0.93", "10.13.0.104"]    

storm.local.dir: "/data1/storm/state"    

storm.log.dir: "/data1/storm/log"    

nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data1/storm/log/gc-storm-nimbus.log"    

worker.childopts: "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data1/storm/log/gc-storm-worker-%ID%.log"    

supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data1/storm/log/gc-storm-supervisor.log"    

supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703

client.jartransformer.class: "org.apache.storm.hack.StormShadeTransformer"
```

When I run `bin/storm nimbus` on 10.13.0.91, I can see the nimbus progress bind to 10.13.0.91.

However, when I run the same command with same configuration

```
tcp        0      0 :::6627                     :::*                        LISTEN      54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:6627       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:34507      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:46929     ::ffff:10.13.0.91:6627      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:53760     ::ffff:10.13.0.93:2181      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:34495      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:6627       ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:46944     ::ffff:10.13.0.91:6627      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:20261     ::ffff:10.13.0.91:2181      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:20175     ::ffff:10.13.0.91:2181      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:26995     ::ffff:10.13.0.104:2181     ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:46949     ::ffff:10.13.0.91:6627      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.13.0.93:26994     ::ffff:10.13.0.104:2181     ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:6627       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:34495      ESTABLISHED 54981/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:34507      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:6627       ESTABLISHED 54981/java
```

Searched a long time on google but nothing help. Does any one meet the same issue before?

Comment: can I know why did you set same zookeeper ips(storm.zookeeper.servers) to storm nimbus also ?

Comment: @DilipBobby Just because I ran zookeeper cluster and storm cluster in the same machines : )

Answer (score 0):

add this line in storm.yaml

```
storm.local.hostname: "your-host-name"
```

and put **your-host-name** in **/etc/hosts** and restart storm-nimbus